# What is the Old English(Ænȝlıſc/Eald Englisc/Anglo Saxon) Word for "Grammatical Case?"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, old-english

I am curious as to what the Ænȝlıſc word is for "grammatical case." I remembered hearing a man say it before, but I cannot remember for sure. If I recall, he said something along the lines of "ſe Fæle," which is the same gender as, and very similar to the German word: "der Falle."

I thank any for any in advance.

Comment: That looks to me like just a calque of the German rather than "authentic" Old English as we know it was spoken. But it may not matter much, since the German is a calque of the Latin, which is if I remember correctly a calque of the Greek word for "case."

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I managed to find the video, and he said any of: se fyll, se fiell, þæt fyll, or þæt fiell... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmI5ag1s38E two completely different Genders, two completely different pronunciations.

Comment: The OED says the Old English word for "fall" was "fięll, fyll ( < *falli-z)" Apparently it could be masculine or neuter: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiell  Wiktionary also says it did mean "case," apparently

Comment: okay, thanks. I guess that can be the answer... I do thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wiktionary, "se/þæt **fiell**," either masculine or neuter, can also mean "grammatical case."

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiell